# How to get uniques in column A and totals from column B?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet that looks like this:

```
A            B
DeptA        10
DeptB        5
DeptA        5
DeptA        10
DeptC        5
DeptB        10
DeptA        20
DeptB        5
```

I'm trying to get a list of the unique values in A, and then the total in B for each unique value. The output I'm looking for is this, which can go in columns C/D (or wherever, doesn't matter)

```
DeptA        45
DeptB        20
DeptC        5
```

I know I can pull the uniques in A and place them in C with the following array formula:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$8, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($C$1:C1, $A$2:$A$8), 0))
```

How to list the column B totals along with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No formula is necessary.

For example, uniques may be obtained (avoiding COUNTIF, INDEX and MATCH) with Data > Sort & Filter – Advanced , Copy to another location selected, Unique records only checked and Copy to: set to `C1` (though my version is a bit temperamental and at present also requires deleting C1 and sorting).

But with sorting (select A:B, Data > Sort & Filter – AZ) then subtotal can be used (insert a new row as Row1, select `A:B` Data > Outline – Subtotal, OK , OK [defaults are probably as required: At each change in: (Column A), Use function: Sum, Add subtotal to: (Column B), Replace current subtotals, Summary below data] then click on small ‘2’ at the top left.

Grand Total is a bonus.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the [DSUM](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/dsum-function-HP010342460.aspx?CTT=1) Function as it's less work than pivoting.

EDIT: Corrected URL

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your current construct and do a `sumif` or `sumifs` (they have different order of the arguments) in column D based on column C that sums column B.

Alternatively you can use a pivot table to get the complete result for you. Note however that a pivot requires manual refreshing, where the formulas will auto update when calculation is set to automatic